# Link to current window within a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, window

folks!

I'm an absolute beginner in JavaScript and I'm trying to get a specific condition within a JavaScript function (passwd=="eggplant) to open a link in the same window. I've tried the "window.location.href" (currently on the code), "window.location" and "location" objects, as well as the "window.location.replace()" function, but they didn't work. I should also point out that I'm using a separate .js file to write the scripts.

Here's the whole function:

```
function colorFunc()
{
  var passwd = document.getElementById("pass").value;
  if(passwd=="614051"){
  window.open ('color1.html')
  }

  else if(passwd=="eggplant" || passwd=="Eggplant" || passwd=="EGGPLANT"){
  window.location.href = 'color2.html';
  }

  else{
  alert('You have got the answer wrong!');
  }
}
```

All the other conditions work, and I could even open "color2.html" using "window.open". Could you, more experienced users, please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Edit:

Here's the relevant portion of my .html file.

```
<form name="input">
<input id="pass" name="Answer" placeholder="Your answer"></input>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="colorFunc()"></input>
</form>
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(DEMO **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/HY6yp/show/)**)

Use this on your html onclick:

```
onclick="colorFunc(this)"
```

and then inside your javascript function `colorFunc(e)` add `e.preventDefault;` to prevent from submiting the form. You don't need to use a form for this behavour you show here, but maybe you need it for other code. Anyway this should work.

HTML

```
<input id="pass" name="Answer" value="614051" placeholder="Your answer"></input>
<button type="button" value="Submit" onclick="colorFunc(this)">Send</button>
```

JS

```
function colorFunc(e)
{
  var passwd = document.getElementById("pass").value;
  if(passwd=="614051"){
  window.open ('color1.html','_self'))
  }

  else if(passwd=="eggplant" || passwd=="Eggplant" || passwd=="EGGPLANT"){
  window.open('color2.html','_self'));
  }

  else{
  alert('You have got the answer wrong!');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Sergio. Actually, I negleted to put the relevant portion of my .html file. Sorry about that. The thing is, the function is called - if I use the code identical to yours, it works great. However, I wanted to open the "else if" related link in the current window. That's where I'm having problems.

Comment: @DaviFariaDeConti, just updated my answer. Check the demo. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Thanks, Sergio! I made the adjustments you suggested and they do work great, but I can't get the links to open in the same window (instead of in a new one, which happens by using `window.open`).

Comment: @DaviFariaDeConti you can use the second parameter of window.open which is were to open it. Try: window.open `('YourNewPage.htm','_self')`

Comment: Thanks, Sergio, but, for some reason, it doesn't work... It now looks like this: `else if(passwd=="eggplant" || passwd=="Eggplant" || passwd=="EGGPLANT"){
      window.open = 'color2.html','_self';
      }`

Comment: Sorry! It actually looks like this:`else if(passwd=="eggplant" || passwd=="Eggplant" || passwd=="EGGPLANT"){ window.open ('color2.html','_self'); }`

Comment: @DaviFariaDeConti, just another question to answer you better. Do you need the form? to post to a database? or you need just the input to check the password?

Comment: Hey, Sergio! I just need the input to check the password. I don't even have a database - it's just a game I'm going to use in the classroom.

Comment: @DaviFariaDeConti, I edited my answer now. If you don't need the form your code can be more simple and have less chances to not work for you.

Comment: @DaviFariaDeConti, great!